# Difference between request_irq() and setup_irq()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Whats the difference between request_irq and setup_irq?

When to use request_irq()
when to go with setup_irq()

Comment: `request_irq` calls to `setup_irq`

Answer (score 3):

From the kernel source, kernel/irq/manage.c, setup_irq() is "Used to statically setup interrupts in the early boot process."

request_irq() is the function that you would use under most circumstances.